# How to understand and decrease Innodb_rows_read.avg?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, innodb

I am looking to understand what's behind Innodb_rows_read value and how to decrease it. For some unknown reasons my RDS server has been over 90% of CPU for more than 5 days and after investigation, the only metric that matches the increase is the Innodb_rows_read.

[image]

How can it be 1 million rows/sec when the application is only used by a few thousands of users per day?

Here is the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`

```
2022-05-01 11:39:29 0x4000e7765020 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT

Per second averages calculated from the last 47 seconds

BACKGROUND THREAD

srv_master_thread loops: 191329 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 8 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0

SEMAPHORES

OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 85936
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 76904631
RW-shared spins 56640596, rounds 56686613, OS waits 12564
RW-excl spins 7722161, rounds 5031065, OS waits 18459
RW-sx spins 911, rounds 25664, OS waits 450
Spin rounds per wait: 1.00 RW-shared, 0.65 RW-excl, 28.17 RW-sx
--
TRANSACTIONS
--
Trx id counter 21253896
Purge done for trx's n:o < 21253896 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 5
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
TRANSACTION 351844895300328, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
TRANSACTION 351844895298616, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
TRANSACTION 351844895302896, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
TRANSACTION 351844895299472, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
TRANSACTION 351844895306320, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
TRANSACTION 351844895297760, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
TRANSACTION 351844895296904, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
TRANSACTION 351844895296048, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
TRANSACTION 351844895295192, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)

FILE I/O

I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 134
108319 OS file reads, 784313 OS file writes, 294198 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s

INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX

Ibuf: size 1, free list len 92, seg size 94, 69 merges
merged operations:
insert 146, delete mark 6, delete 2
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 2921951, node heap has 1592 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2921951, node heap has 1027 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2921951, node heap has 280 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2921951, node heap has 524 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2921951, node heap has 1704 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2921951, node heap has 3016 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2921951, node heap has 5097 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2921951, node heap has 93 buffer(s)
1300755.83 hash searches/s, 66516.05 non-hash searches/s

LOG

Log sequence number          208556928494
Log buffer assigned up to    208556928494
Log buffer completed up to   208556928494
Log written up to            208556928494
Log flushed up to            208556928494
Added dirty pages up to      208556928494
Pages flushed up to          208537388287
Last checkpoint at           208537388287
591712 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second

BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY

Total large memory allocated 12053381120
Dictionary memory allocated 1367902
Buffer pool size   720894
Free buffers       589274
Database pages     118287
Old database pages 43502
Modified db pages  549
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 973309, not young 2165274
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 108091, created 11412, written 120290
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 118287, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]

INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO

BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   90112
Free buffers       73975
Database pages     14485
Old database pages 5327
Modified db pages  86
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 15403, not young 190139
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 13171, created 1434, written 16714
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 14485, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   90112
Free buffers       73461
Database pages     14975
Old database pages 5507
Modified db pages  153
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 24439, not young 49726
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 13681, created 1485, written 16762
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 14975, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   90111
Free buffers       73555
Database pages     14900
Old database pages 5480
Modified db pages  16
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 835706, not young 1034404
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 13724, created 1423, written 19447
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 14900, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   90111
Free buffers       73901
Database pages     14549
Old database pages 5350
Modified db pages  8
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 18943, not young 155321
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 13440, created 1196, written 6336
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 14549, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   90112
Free buffers       73419
Database pages     15038
Old database pages 5531
Modified db pages  7
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 20069, not young 115857
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 13870, created 1286, written 9751
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 15038, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   90112
Free buffers       73916
Database pages     14504
Old database pages 5334
Modified db pages  73
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 20678, not young 158166
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 13191, created 1446, written 15107
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 14504, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   90112
Free buffers       73874
Database pages     14569
Old database pages 5358
Modified db pages  114
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 19535, not young 240306
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 13070, created 1607, written 16777
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 14569, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   90112
Free buffers       73173
Database pages     15267
Old database pages 5615
Modified db pages  92
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 18536, not young 221355
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 13944, created 1535, written 19396
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 15267, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
-
ROW OPERATIONS
-
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=29214, Main thread ID=70382950289440 , state=sleeping
Number of rows inserted 12846357, updated 21281, deleted 4084052, read 249282821838
41.55 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 1165804.58 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 302, updated 1183, deleted 266, read 6903784
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.36 reads/s
-
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
```

Comment: Your question will be more suitable for `https://superuser.com/` as it's not related to code at all, at least not from what you initially have in your Q.

Comment: No worries, just want you to get an answer quicker :) feel free to delete this Q as it will ultimately be closed

Comment: I would start by looking at the queries that are running. How many are running concurrently, and what are their execution plans? Are there any table scans involved? Also, I'd recommend reposting on https://dba.stackexchange.com/, not superuser (the latter is more for people having problems with their home computers).

Comment: Thanks, I posted it here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/311536/how-to-understand-and-decrease-innodb-rows-read-avg-rds-innodb

Would you know how to look at queries being run in real-time or last x sec? That'd indeed help me solve the issue. I'm using RDS Slow Query reporting but it does not give the volume only the wait time.